# React - toggle css class but do not rerender everything

Tags: reactjs

I have a Gatsby website and I want to use it to show flashcards. I have found multiple existing solutions online, but I would like to try it a different way. However, I am completely stuck.

**Desired result:**
Show one random word at a time. When the users clicks on a button 'show', the meaning of the word should be shown.

**Issue:**
I can generate a random combination of the words. But when the user clicks on 'show', a new combination is loaded instead of the answer. I understand why this happens. However, I do not understand how to fix this.

I have tried this (stripped to the bare essentials):

```
export const Flashcard = () => {
  const [flip, setFlip] = useState(false)

  const onButtonClick = () => {
    setFlip(!flip)
  }


  let word = words[GenerateRandomNumber(0, words.length - 1)] // words is an array containing all the possible combinations

  return (
    <div className={`card ${flip ? "flip" : ""}`}>
      <div className="front">
        {word["language1"]}
      </div>
      <div className="back">
        {word["language2"]}
      </div>
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Show answer</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Flashcard
```

I feel like I am on a totally wrong path, but don't see how to fix it. Should I structure my logic different? Should I use some other hooks? Or anything else?

In addition, I would also like the user having the possibility to say he knew the meaning (clicking on a button 'correct') or not (button 'wrong'). If correct, a new word is shown, if wrong, the word is stored to be shown later again. How should I trigger this logic?

Comment: Try moving `let word = words..` outside the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add a state to store the picked word

```
const [word, setWord] = useState("");
```

and When you do a click you need to get a random word and store in `word`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const randomNumber = GenerateRandomNumber(0, words.length - 1);
    const newWord = words[randomNumber];
    setWord(newWord);
}, [flip]); //This useEffect will call everytime when flip change.
```

in return you can refer the word

```
{word["language1"]}
```

here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4rv4wc)